# Master Check Box in AG Grid on any column

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

[Master Checkbox in Ag Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSrbM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSrbM.png)

Need to add a check box on top just before Client Name column as Master Check Box to select all rows.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your column definition part just add this to Client name column def:

```
headerCheckboxSelection: true,
checkboxSelection: true,
```